# Creating an sqlite database using command line shell in windows

Tags: sqlite

I have my sqlite3.exe file in `C:\` and i want to create an sqlite database in `C:\db\sqlite`.I have tried sqlite3 ex1 as suggested on the docs http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html but i get the error Error Near "sqlite3".

What is the correct way of creating a new database from the shell?.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is one way to use SQLite3 from the command prompt in Windows.

First you need to know the path to the folder where you installed the [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/). If you used the default settings this would be C:\Program Files\SQLite ODBC Driver on Windows XP

**Go to Start -> Run -> type cmd -> click OK**

[image: Type cmd]

This opens the command prompt.

[image: Command prompt]

In the Shell, type in the following command. You can use Alt + Space if you prefer to use cut and paste. Remember to modify the path for your setup if you installed SQLite in another folder.

**cd C:\Program Files\SQLite ODBC Driver**

[image: Path to folder]

This brings you to the SQLite install folder. Now you are ready to call SQLite. Type the following command at the SQLite prompt.

**sqlite3**

[image: Call SQLite]

This opens the File menu where you can choose a database to connect to, or create a new database file.

[image: File menu]

Navigate to *C:\db\sqlite* and create *myDatabase.db*, and click *Open* to close the file menu.

Now you are ready to work on your new database, run your queries, e.g. create a table.

[image: Create table]

Comment: I tried opening the command line and used "sqlite3 DatabaseName.db" as well as using the same using sqlite command line shell application but nothing seems to work, I used ".open DatabaseName.db" in both the cases and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

As new file is created in current directory, for creating file at different location you should follow this format:

eg. for storing file FILENAME.db at c:/users/xyz/abc
you should type

```
sqlite>.open c:/users/xyz/abc/FILENAME.db
```

and then press enter a new file will be created at the mentioned path.

and now when you will type `.databases` you will see your file listed in the list of databases.

Comment: Far simpler than the top answer!

Comment: I wonder why the top answer not worked for me but this worked?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following command to create the sqlite database

.open databasename.db

or

.open c:/somefolder/databasename.db